# Regarding Java JDK Environment Variable settings on Windows 10

Tags: java

I have installed Java SE Development kit 8u102. `javac` command executes properly. I saved a Demo.java file on public desktop. While compiling the Demo.java file I got the error as :

```
javac: file not found: Demo.java
```

I have done the following changes in the Environment variable tab:

user variables for Siddharth:

```
JAVA_HOME Value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
```

System variables:

```
Path Variable Value = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin
```

Comment: I have even tried the path with variable value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin

Comment: "I saved a Demo.java file on public desktop" - since javac says the file not found it seems you are running command form a different directory. So move the Demo.java to where you run your command or add the public desktop folder to PATH

Comment: Check https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Comment: @Maharaj I have tired exactly wts given there.  I even tested the same. javac - version gave me the result as "javac 1.8.0_102 "                  but java - version gave me a error as "The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java|javapath\java.exe"

Comment: Can you show us your command from the command line you use to use javac?

Comment: @Blobonat,@Maharaj The issue has been resolved know. Thanks for being there.